# DotNetNuke 6.0 how to save values in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetnuke

I am using DotNetNuke 6.0 and created my own register form but the values are not inserting into the database so please help me how to save values in database.

Comment: Code snippet? so we can see what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

The main thing that you need to be concerned with in terms of interacting with the database in DotNetNuke is that you should get the connection string from [`Config.GetConnectionString()`](http://dotnetnukeru.com/Dnn6Docs/api/html/M_DotNetNuke_Common_Utilities_Config_GetConnectionString.htm).  If the site uses an object qualifier or non-dbo database owner/schema (or it's a commercial extension), you'll have a couple more things to consider, but otherwise, it shouldn't be any different how you'd save to the database in any other context.

Any specifics of what you're trying would definitely help us point you in the right direction.